# Calendar Display link is somewhat hidden

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

On the Profile Page I was hunting around to find the calendar which shows me when I was active and what not. It took me a while to find because it wasn't an obvious link.

After running some tests I found this. When you initially load the page in Chrome and Firefox <s>and some stupid thing called Internet Explorer</s> the mouse doesn't show the usual pointer as you would get with a link.

[image: screen shot]

But when you do click on it the style is updated to have the mouse show the pointer showing it's a link.

[image: screen shot]

I'm probably just being anal about this given I love looking at my calendar every now and again but it's kinda easy for the calendar to now be missed by new users as in the old design when you hover over the next the mouse becomes the pointer showing it's a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed and deployed network-wide.